# Getting sensor data from an S9706 through an optocoupler is not working

Tags: sensor, opto-isolator

I am using a [Hamamatsu Photonics S9706 color sensor](https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/product/optical-sensors/photo-ic/color-sensor/rgb-color-sensor/S9706.html) ([datasheet](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/s9706_kpic1060e.pdf)) with an ESP32S3. The four sensor data lines are connected to the microcontroller input using an [ILQ621 optocoupler](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83654/ild621.pdf).

Without the optocoupler, I am able to read the sensor data correctly.  When I use the optocoupler I don't get the right data.
I am using a low-pass filter, too.

Here is the schematic:

[image]

On the ESP32 site I read always (Red:255, Green:xx, Blue:xx)
I have tried without the low-pass filter -> not working.

Answer (score 4):

There are four lines used in reading data from the S9706:

[image]

Three of those are driven by the microprocessor reading the data:

1. Range
2. Gate
3. CK (clock)

Only \$D_{out}\$ goes from the S9706 to the microcontroller.

You need to connect the Range, Gate, and CK signals to the other side of the optocoupler - optocouplers only work in one direction.

You also don't need the "filter" part of your circuit.  The filter is set up to clean up the signals coming from the S9706, but three of the signals actually go to the S9706.

---

Since you have the same ground on both sides of the optocoupler, there's not much point in even having it in the circuit.

---

The signals all go this way in your circuit:

[image]

Three of them actually need to go the other direction, but can't because optcouplers are only one way:

[image]

---

Since you said in comments that you are only using the optocouplers on the data lines, I had another look at your circuit.

It turns out that when there's a high on the data line, your circuit delivers a low to the microprocessor - the way you have the optocouplers wired inverts the signals.

Remove the optocouplers entirely.  They are doing you any good.  Optocouplers are used to isolate systems.  Since you have the other signal lines wired directly, there's no isolation and hence no need to use the optoisolators.

Comment: I am using the optpcoupler only for the four data lines.
The Gate, Range and Clock lines are directly connected to the sensors.

Comment: I will probably not use them anymore, but i still want to understand why it is not working with the optocouplers

Comment: Did you have the ground wires connected?

Comment: @Hamo: If the gate, range, and clock lines are directly connected, then there's no need to use the optocouplers on the data lines. Optocouplers are used to isolate systems. You are not isolating anything, so don't use them.

Comment: Yes i did connected the Ground wires